# Read UTF-8 encoded text content inside table cell in MS-word file using Apache POI

Tags: java, utf-8, apache-poi

I'm trying to read a table and exact data in a Microsoft Word document (docx file) using apache poi. The file contain UTF-8 encoded characters (Sinhala language). I'm using following code block.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("path\\to\\file.docx");
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
Iterator<IBodyElement> iter = doc.getBodyElementsIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    IBodyElement elem = iter.next();
    if (elem instanceof XWPFTable) {
        List<XWPFTableRow> rows = ((XWPFTable) elem).getRows();
        for(XWPFTableRow row :rows){
            List<XWPFTableCell> cells = row.getTableCells();
            for(XWPFTableCell cell : cells){
                PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
                out.println(cell.getText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not getting correct UTF-8 characters in the output console.

[image: console output]

I have already refer several solutions including following.

[How to parse UTF-8 characters in Excel files using POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202505/how-to-parse-utf-8-characters-in-excel-files-using-poi) | I'm trying to read a table in a Word file. So my `Cell` object doesn't have `getStringCellValue()` method.

http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/native2ascii-Set-UTF-8-Encoding-in-PrintStream.html | I have already tried this solution and It's not working.

does anyone know how to read UTF-8 encoded characters in a word file using apache poi?

Comment: Have you tried `URLEncoder.encode(cell.getText(), "UTF-8")` ? and print this instead?

Comment: @alirabiee, just tried and its not working either. anyway the text is not an URL.

Comment: This is a problem with the console settings of your IDE. Which IDE is used? Normally `System.out.println(cell.getText());` should work. No explicit `PrintStream` definition needed.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter, I'm using Intellij IDEA. Yes, it was a IDE console font related problem. I just copied the text from the IDE console and paste to Notepad. Then characters are showed correctly. I tried to change IDE console font but couldn't able to find a way to do it. Anyway can you post your answer as a answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with setting font for a cell (as a peragraph).

code :

```
private static final String FILE_NAME = "/tmp/Diskade.docx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME);
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);

        Iterator<IBodyElement> iter = doc.getBodyElementsIterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            IBodyElement elem = iter.next();
            if (elem instanceof XWPFTable) {

                List<XWPFTableRow> rows = ((XWPFTable) elem).getRows();
                for(XWPFTableRow row :rows){
                    List<XWPFTableCell> cells = row.getTableCells();

                    for(XWPFTableCell cell : cells){

                        String celltext = cell.getText();
                        XWPFParagraph paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
                        setRun(paragraph.createRun() , "Arial" , 10, "2b5079" , celltext , false, false);
                        System.out.print(cell.getParagraphs().get(0).getParagraphText() + " - ");

                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void setRun (XWPFRun run , String fontFamily , int fontSize , String colorRGB , String text , boolean bold , boolean addBreak) {
        run.setFontFamily(fontFamily);
        run.setFontSize(fontSize);
        run.setColor(colorRGB);
        run.setText(text);
        run.setBold(bold);
        if (addBreak) run.addBreak();
    }
```

**EDIT : 

Later I noted that, actually adding paragraph is enough. You don't need setRun method or invokin it as `setRun(paragraph.createRun() , "Arial" , 10, "2b5079" , celltext , false, false);`.**

[image]

Will see is there anything can be done with encoding. (because, for me once the font is loaded it was working fine without paragraph also)

Comment: This solution works with eclipse, but not with Intelij IDEA which is I'm using right now. Actually later I have noticed that this is a IDE console problem and not a program error.